# Count or/and list only unique items of a WordPress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is an example loop:

```
$args = array('s' => 'Example search term', 'cat' => 100, 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
            echo $category->cat_name . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Assuming that the category with the id# 100 is a parent category for several subcategories, this loop successfully returns a list of heavily duplicated category names.

How could I list only **unique** category names and count them? And put both values into appropriate variables.

Along with the complete list of all found results and their count, too...

*Of course I'll try to figure out the solution myself while waiting for your kind answer, as always. But, actually, a little help would be much appreciated.*

Comment: You could `array_unique` on the array you want to make it unique. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @Perumal93, Thank you for just the clue, not the ready answer. I've checked the PHP manuals and now have the solution which I've done myself.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'll respond to myself. Again )

Thanks to @Perumal93's hint which directed me the correct way, I now have the solution.

In case it would be usable for anyone like me, here is the commented code ready for copy and paste:

```
$args = array('s' => 'Example search term', 'cat' => 100, 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$categories = array(); // 1. Defining the empty array outside of the loop
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
            $categories[] = $category->cat_name; // 2. Filling the array with required data
        }
    }
$u_categories = array_unique($categories); // 3. Clearing the array from repeated data
$u_categories_cnt = count($u_categories); // 4. Counting the cleared array items

foreach( $u_categories as $category ) {                                  // 5. Outputting
    if($category == end($u_categories)) { echo $category.'.'; }          //    the cleared
    elseif($category == prev($u_categories)) { echo $category.' and '; } //    array in a
    else {echo $category.', '; }                                         //    human
}                                                                        //    friendly way

echo $u_categories_cnt; // 6. Outputting the cleared array items count
}
wp_reset_query();
```

That's it